# Ошибка при использовании npm пакета: The keyword 'interface' is reserved

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

Я решил выложить свой npm пакет т.к посчитал, что он будет полезен не только мне, но и другим людям. Когда я пытаюсь скачать свой же пакет в другой проект, в браузере выходит ошибка:

```
The keyword 'interface' is reserved (3:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

Ссылка на мой пакет: https://github.com/rassadin11/rainfall-animation

Если нужна дополнительная информация, попросите дополнить вопрос.
Пожалуйста, помогите найти проблему и исправить её.

Comment: наверное, при подключении вашей библиотеки в браузере ожидается скомпилированный js, но браузер получает исходник на typescript

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что слово interface уже зарезервировано javascript для использования в будущем. Для того чтобы js понимал, что interface принадлежит typescript, необходимо переконфигурировать standardjs на ts-standart.